# The type of property not the same when reading from input stream

Tags: json, go, struct, numbers

The code used for testing for listing users.

```
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/v1/users", nil)
    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()

    u.app.ServeHTTP(resp, req)

    if resp.Code != http.StatusOK {
        t.Fatalf("getting users: expected status code %v, got %v", http.StatusOK, resp.Code)
    }

    var list []map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&list); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("decoding users: %s", err)
    }

    want := []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "id":           "a2b0639f-2cc6-44b8-b97b-15d69dbb511e",
            "name":         "dcc",
            "role_id":      float64(101),
            "date_created": "2019-01-01T00:00:01Z",
            "date_updated": "2019-01-01T00:00:01Z",
        },
    }
```

The role_id is a int type in model.

```
type User struct {
    ID          string    `db:"user_id" json:"id"`
    UserName    string    `db:"user_name" json:"user_name"`
    RoleID      int       `db:"role_id" json:"role_id"`
    DateCreated time.Time `db:"date_created" json:"date_created"`
    DateUpdated time.Time `db:"date_updated" json:"date_updated"`
}
```

Why it is changed to float64 when inputing to the stream?

Comment: "To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores [...] float64, for JSON numbers." https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal Don't use empty interfaces if you care about types. You already have a User type, so why decode a (slice of) map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.RoleID` is an integer, and it will be encoded into a JSON Number. And
because you unmarshal into a value of type `map[string]interface{}` (the value type is interface), `float64` type is chosen when unmarshaling into an interface value.

Quoting from [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/):

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

If you know the response holds a `User` object, unmarshal into a value of type `User`.